# nginx unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:20 over Raspbian

Tags: nginx, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm new at nginx and Raspberry.

I installed nginx using

> sudo apt-get install

And everything was fine at that point. The problem came when I tried to restart nginx, It threw this error

> Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status ngins.service' and 'journaldtl -xn' for details

After an investigation I found that the problem is the next error:

> unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:20

My default file is:

```
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
## 

server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
    listen 80;
    server_name $domain_name;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;



    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location /
```

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: can you show the 20th line in default file ?

Comment: Is exactly the line below  :location /
I tried writing ´}´ but it doesn't work. In fact I didn't modify that file :/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Confirmed there was a missing `;` at the end of a new added line inside the server block `{...}` .

Ensure the curly braces and `;` are **all in place**.

For example line like this will give error,

```
server_name localhost
```

Adding ';' to end like this will fix it

```
server_name localhost;
```

Comment: Thanks.I just missed a “;” at the end of a new added line inside the location block {}.

Answer (score 17):

My issue was due to missing a `;` as part of one of the command line arguments.

For reference here are my logs:

```
2020/08/11 17:19:25 [emerg] 1#1: unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
```

My mistake was I started `nginx` with the following `CMD` via docker:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off"]
```

Where I was missing the trailing `;`. What I should have had was:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Just in case it helps anybody else out.

Comment: Gah, so easy to miss. I'm pouring over my config and could not find it. This was exactly it.

Comment: I was losing my mind! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

as @Thanh Nguyen Van has answered already. the `location` has to be opened and closed in curly braces and then another curly brace for your server's end

```
server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    listen 80;
    server_name $domain_name;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure you have no unexpected quotes (single nor double). It took me a while to figure out one time when I was using Docker and passing the value as an env var, so it was mistakenly quoted.

So, this will be an incorrect bit:

```
upstream backend {
    "server localhost:9000;"
}
```

This is a correct one:

```
upstream backend {
    server localhost:9000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct your nginx file as below :

For example:

```
http {


       upstream api-app {
        .....................;   

        }
        ........................; 
        server {

              location / {
               ...................;
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

              }
        }

}
```

Make sure `;` at the end of line, and `{ ..}` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me I forgot to put `server` before the `{`

Answer (score 0):

Just posting my issue as well.

My dockerfile includes envsubst so I needed to use alt character for '$' to be preserved.

Docker CMD:
`CMD envsubst < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | sed -e 's/§/$/g' > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'`

Set proxy host:
`proxy_set_header Host §http_host;`